# Watir-Webdriver - Parsing through table and clicking start/stop toggle

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

Please be gentle. I'm very new to Ruby and Watir. In general also new to UI automation testing. I'm trying to parse through a table then click a toggle that start/stops an application. The applications that can be turned on and off are not set. They can range from 1 to 'infinite' number applications. I need something that will parse through each row and click the toggle. if the application is started, I need to turn it off and vice-versa. No matter how many rows exist. The row also contains an element in the first column that allows the application to be clicked and brought to another page that gives details about said application. The toggle exists in the last column of the table. Here is the HTML I'm looking at with two applications deployed. It may be something simple that I'm missing. I'm also normally an IT admin that just got thrown into this. Thanks for all the help

```
<table id="apps_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ng-scope">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="link ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in services.data | orderBy:services.sort">
      <td class="ng-binding" ng-click="click_app(app.Id)">Zenoss</td>
      <td class="ng-binding deploy-success" ng-class="app.deploymentClass">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-class="app.deploymentIcon"></span>
        successful
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding">default</td>
      <td>
        <div class="toggle btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="ng-binding btn btn-success active" ng-click="clickRunning(app, 'start', servicesService)" ng-class="app.runningClass">
            <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" value="1" ng-model="app.Running" name="running0">
            started
          </label>
          <label class="ng-binding btn btn-default off" ng-click="clickRunning(app, 'stop', servicesService)" ng-class="app.notRunningClass">
            <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" value="stopped" ng-model="app.Running" name="running0">
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="link ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in services.data | orderBy:services.sort">
      <td class="ng-binding" ng-click="click_app(app.Id)">Zenoss</td>
      <td class="ng-binding deploy-success" ng-class="app.deploymentClass">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-class="app.deploymentIcon"></span>
        successful
      </td>
      <td class="ng-binding">default</td>
      <td>
        <div class="toggle btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="ng-binding btn btn-success active" ng-click="clickRunning(app, 'start', servicesService)" ng-class="app.runningClass">
            <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" value="1" ng-model="app.Running" name="running1">
            started
          </label>
          <label class="ng-binding btn btn-default off" ng-click="clickRunning(app, 'stop', servicesService)" ng-class="app.notRunningClass">
            <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" value="stopped" ng-model="app.Running" name="running1">
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this so far, but it's just going to the first line.

```
 if ff.div(:class, 'toggle btn-group').label(:class, 'ng-binding btn btn-success active').exist?
    ff.div(:class, 'toggle btn-group').label(:class, 'ng-binding btn btn-default off').click; sleep 1
  ff.div(:class, 'toggle btn-group').label(:class, 'ng-binding btn btn-default off').exist?
    ff.div(:class, 'toggle btn-group').label(:class, 'ng-binding btn btn-default off').click; sleep 1
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
apps = browser.table(:id => 'apps_data').tbody.trs
apps.each do |app|
    set_radios = app.radios.find_all{ |radio| !radio.set? }
    if set_radios.length == 2
        # Neither radio button is set, so do nothing? 
    else
        set_radios.first.set
    end
end
```

What this does is:

1. Gets a collection of all tr elements in the table body. Each tr element is assumed to represent an "app".
2. Iterates through each row (app):

   1. Counts the number of radio buttons that are not set.
   2. If neither of the 2 radio buttons is set, it does nothing.
   3. If only one unset radio button is found, it is set.

Note that since the 2 radio buttons of the app have the same name attribute value, setting the one radio button will automatically unset the other.

Comment: Thanks Justin. The collection of the tr elements portion really helps. Setting radios for some reason does not work. When I was trying things out earlier, trying to set radios didn't work. I had to rely on a click for the toggle to move properly.

Comment: It looks like the radio's label might only be waiting for click events. So the else statement could be changed to `set_radios.first.parent.click` (ie click the parent label).

Comment: Thanks again, Justin. I think it has to do something with radios. Seems like it just won't recognize there are radio buttons there. The only thing that's worked for me has been xpath, css, and label class. This is frustrating since radios haven't worked for me. Xpath and CSS worked but only for the first line row.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if you are saying that this code is not working for you. Are you saying that you cannot locate radio buttons at all? Can you locate the radio buttons when following the Watir examples - http://watir.com/examples/?

Comment: Justin, Sorry for the confusion. That is correct, radio buttons cannot be located at all. It seems to point to the fact that the radio buttons do not have unique IDs.

Comment: What exactly is the exception you get?

Comment: irb(main):006:0> ff.radio(:value => 'stopped').set
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: I can get the count of both values of the radio..this is confusing. 

irb(main):068:0> ff.radios(:value => '1').count
=> 2
irb(main):069:0> ff.radios(:value => 'stopped').count
=> 2
irb(main):070:0>

Comment: The exception suggests that the radio button is not visible to the user, but does exist in the DOM. That is why you can get the counts correctly, but not set it. I presume you can see the radio buttons? If you create a page with just the html that you posted in your question, does the code work? If it does, then that suggests that there is something special about your webpage that is confusing Watir.

Comment: An alternative is to bypass the selenium logic that ensures the element is visible and directly set it via javascript. You can change the `set_radios.first.set` statement to `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].checked="true"', set_radios.first)`

Comment: If I create a page with the HTML I entered above, the radio buttons do show. I also tried the javascript snippet you gave, and that doesn't work either. I'm just really curious as to what the webpage is doing that's "special".

Comment: I am running out of ideas as it works fine locally for me. Maybe check that your browser and your gems are up to date?

Comment: Is it possible I'm not requiring a "gem" that is needed? 

require_relative 'config'
require 'rubygems'
require "test/unit"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"
require "rspec"

Comment: I do not believe it is a missing gem. It is an issue with how selenium is interpreting your webpage. What version of selenium-webdriver do you have installed?

Comment: I have selenium-webdriver 2.38
watir-webdriver 0.6.4
watir 5.0.0